# Set focus on a form element in a page with multiple jQuery UI modal dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

**Context**

I have a page with multiple jQuery modals. Each modal contains a form. So you click on a button, it opens this modal, you input something and you close the modal.

I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery.

**What I want**

I want to set focus on a control in the modal when it is displays. I'm using autofocus, which works perfectly for the first modal that is opened.

**The problem**

It only works for the first modal that is opened. When it closes and you open a new one, then the autofocus does not work.

Here is some code. So I have a few of these on the page:

```html
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-section">Create</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="new-section" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" &times; data-dismiss="modal"</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Plan</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <form action="http://nessy.local:8888/master_section/new_section" name="new_section" id="new_section" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="title">Title</label>
                   <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" name="title" autofocus>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save" />
                <input type="hidden" name="master_section_id" value="2">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try replicating the issue in fiddler. this one seems to show nothing about the issue you are facing!